# C# and Ghostscript 64bit

Tags: c#, c++, api, pinvoke, ghostscript

I'm writing open source **C# Ghostscript wrapper**. You can try it and take a look at (**http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com**). Most of the functionality is implemented and it works on     both versions (**x86/x64**). The problem i'm having is when i'm initializing a display device to render pdf directly to the screen (i successfully implemented **gsapi_set_display_callback callback**).

Arguments that i'm using are following:

```
string[] args = new string[] {
    "",
    "-sDEVICE=display",
    "-dTextAlphaBits=4",
    "-dGraphicAlphaBits=4",
    "-dDisplayHandle=1234",
    "-dDisplayResolution=72",
    "-dDisplayFormat=" + ((int)DISPLAY_FORMAT_COLOR.DISPLAY_COLORS_RGB | 
                            (int)DISPLAY_FORMAT_ALPHA.DISPLAY_ALPHA_NONE | 
                            (int)DISPLAY_FORMAT_DEPTH.DISPLAY_DEPTH_8 | 
                            (int)DISPLAY_FORMAT_ENDIAN.DISPLAY_LITTLEENDIAN | 
                            (int)DISPLAY_FORMAT_FIRSTROW.DISPLAY_BOTTOMFIRST).ToString() };
```

This arguments **works well on 32 bit version** and i'm able to render pdf page to the screen. Initialization works fine.

When i switch to the **64 bit version** i get typecheck (**e_typecheck = -20**) error.

I know that 64 bit version uses **-sDisplayFormat** and i tried that also but with no luck.

Anyone has any idea how to initialize device as display on 64 bit version Ghostscript library? I dont think i'm missing something. Is this a bug in 64 bit version of the ghostscript library?

I tried earlier versions of Ghostscript library and i get a same error on 64 bit version.

Current version that i use is 9.09. Class where you can take a look at the code: [**Ghostscript.NET.Viewer.GhostscriptViewer.cs**](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ghostscript.NET/Ghostscript.NET/Viewer/GhostscriptViewer.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. First problem was that for 64-bit version -sDisplayHandle needs to be used as value passed in should be string. 32-bit version use -dDisplayHandle (number value). Second problem was that i had StructureLayout Pack = 1. 64 bit version should be 0.